# PDF Form data retrieve Via REST Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, adobe, acrobat

I need to retrieve data from a web service and populate data on a pdf document.  I would prefer to use JavaScript within the pdf document.  I have tried using XMLHttpRequest to retrieve the data via rest, but it seems that it is not supported by Adobe. From the Javascript Debugger I get `ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined` I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro 2017.

Comment: There is a vast difference between the JavaScript core, JavaScript for browsers, and JavaScript for Acrobat. You can't expect JavaScript objects that are specific to browsers to work in Acrobat. The Acrobat Object you are looking for is "Net.HTTP" and is documented here... https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FNet_HTTP_methods.htm

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am making progress.  From what I understand the Net.Http will return a stream object on success.  How can I read the stream object?

Comment: Look at the util.stringFromStream method. That will pretty much do exactly what it says.